# How to make a jquery full browser page image sideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

There is a method here (http://css-tricks.com/3458-perfect-full-page-background-image/) which I use a lot for making an image fill the entire browser window while retaining its aspect ratio using jQuery, how can I merge this and jQuery serial scroll (http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/serialScroll/) to make a full browser window image slideshow.

Any other method of achieving the same result is welcome

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Comment: Thanks Ive seen this as well will look into it more but I kinda wanna learn how to do it without a plugin, manually if you will